# RallyRestToolkitForRuby - Unable to pull user permissions

Tags: ruby, rally, user-permissions, toolkit

Am trying to use https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby to pull permissions of all users in my Rally Subscription. My authentication is through API Key. It fails with below error:

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Rally-User-Management-master\Rally-User-Management-master>user_permissions_summary.rb
Connecting to Rally: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm as ganra08@ca.com...
Running initial query of users...
Found a total of 12392 Enabled Users.
Summarizing users and writing permission summary output file...
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Rally-User-Management-master/Rally-User-Management-master/lib/go_user_permissions_summary.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in go_user_permissions_summary'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_colle
ction.rb:36:in`each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_collection.rb:36:in `each'
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Rally-User-Management-master/Rally-User-Management-master/lib/go_user_permissions_summary.rb:201:in`block in go_user_permissions_summary'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_query_result.rb:22:in `block in each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_query_result.rb:21:in`each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_api-1.2.1/lib/rally_api/rally_query_result.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Rally-User-Management-master/Rally-User-Management-master/lib/go_user_permissions_summary.rb:180:in`go_user_permissions_summary'

C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Rally-User-Management-master/Rally-User-Management-master/**user_permissions_summary.rb:38:in `<main>' undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass**

How do i get over this error? The Readme.pdf in the GitHub page provides no info about this.

Comment: Please try to format text, especially when posting error backtrace. It's hard to figure out what's the problem. Although as far as I understand you have a specific issue with some gem so it might be better to open an issue at the github repository of this gem.

Comment: OK, ll try to format the error message manually next time.
The GitHub page mentioned posting here for any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Agile Central (formerly Rally) support helped to resolve this.

The *$wsapi_version* variable is set in a couple of places.  We need to ensure that it is set to '1.43', and not 'v2.0'. Then the error went away and the script runs as expected.
If using the my_vars.rb file, comment out both lines of the $wsapi_version and just let the one in the go_user_permissions_summary.rb (1.43) be used.